# Gatsby.js with WordPress

Tags: gatsby

I'm using Gatsbyjs with gatsby-source-wordpress. I can pull posts from the example websites and my other WP blogs, but I can't get it to work on my development site. I have the error :

> cannot read property allWordpressPage of undefined.

Also Gatsby doesn't pull in any posts when I run, `npm run develop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have trouble getting the gatsby-source-wordpress plugin to work. You may need to change the permalinks setting in WP to something other than "Plain" which uses query parameters(www.yoursite.com?p=123).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. What solved it was this:

`npm install --save gatsby@latest`

For some reason source-wordpress needs the latest Gatsby to work. Try it. Hope it works for you.